# My map callouts don't display the image when clicked

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, mapkit, uistoryboard

I am developing an iPhone application for a university project and I'm new to iPhone development. I have looked through Apple's MapCallouts code but it doesn't seem feasible to implement it.

So far my code displays a map, drops annotations, displays the title and it displays the right call out button.  But this is where I encounter problems.

When I press on the callout button, it displays a blank view controller but it should display a different image for every callout that's tapped and this isn't happening so far.

**I have added my code below:**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
        calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    //NSUInteger tag = ((UIButton *)control).tag;

    if (self.detailController==nil)
    {
        DetailViewController* detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];            
    }

   // self.detailController.tag =1; //to identify image required
   // self.detailController.tag = tag;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Show the method that is called when the callout button is pressed.  Edit your question and add the code to it.

Comment: Is detailController showing at all?  Also note your current code will push twice if detailController is nil.  Is this your actual code (you have `detailController` and `detailViewController`)?  Instead of trying to use tags to identify the annotation, it's available directly in view.annotation.  For examples, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256288/how-to-pass-sender-tag-in-detailview-to-get-default-map-application-for-directio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921106/optimizing-code-for-mkmapview-large-number-of-annotations

Comment: When I run the app a view is loading when the call out accessory is tapped but it displays a black blank screen where the image should be and I also get the following error: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: I dont know how to resolve this as I am using storyboards and I do have a new view controller with its own UIViewcontroller class called DetailViewController Im not sure if this should be push or modal though?

Comment: Whether to use push or presentModal is a UI choice not a coding requirement either way. The error is probably caused by the second push in the method (detailController must be nil).  You should work on solving the storyboard/push issue before worrying about the annotation image.  I haven't used storyboard so I can't give specific advice.

Comment: ok i will try to sort that out.

Comment: you don't init a view controller that way, you usually use [[DetaliViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil] so you can give the name of the nib made in Interface builder that is to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard, then you should already have a view controller. I'm assuming your code is in the class that your view controller is an instance of.

The easiest (least coding required) way to present an image is to:

1. Drag a view controller into the storyboard
2. Drag a UIImageView into the view controller
3. Select the image you want to show up in the properties editor of the UIImageview
4. Control-drag from the button in your main view controller to the view controller containing the image
5. This should have created a segue. Select the segue and select "modal" from the style menu

You can do this for each image you want, but it is messy. Consider also subclassing the image controller and programmatically defining the image you want to show up. You may need to do this anyway if you want to dismiss the image with the dismiss modal view controller method. The alternative would be adding another segue that points backward.